# Laravel - Экранирование символов при использовании LIKE в запросе

Tags: mysql, laravel

Как в Laravel экранировать спецсимволы в выражении использующем LIKE? :

```
$kw = '2+2';
where('keywords', 'LIKE', '%' . $kw . '%')
```

чтобы искало именно 2+2, а не 2(пробел)2

Comment: Функции [quotemeta()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.quotemeta.php) или [addcslashes()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.addcslashes.php) не пробовали?

Answer (score 0):

Использовать метод `whereRaw('keywords LIKE %'.$kw.'%')`. Но здесь повышается уязвимость для SQL инъекций

Comment: эта запись формирует такое же выражение `keywords LIKE %2 2%`

Comment: Покажите код, как вы используете метод. А также попробуйте сделать дамп `sql`-запроса перед передачей в метод `whereRaw($sql)`. У меня подозрения, что передаете в запрос необработанные данные из request'а